# urllib.openurl() doesn't open URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib, urlopen

I'm trying to use `urllib.openurl()` like that:

```
import urllib
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url="https://www.otcmarkets.com")
```

But it just doesn't work for some reason. If I give different HTTPS url like 'https://www.google.com' it works but for some websites like this one I just can't open the url. Can I do something to make it work?
Do you have another way to extract html from website?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

The website checks if you set a User-Agent in the headers. The requests-package makes it easy to use urllib.
You can do what you want by using something like that:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get("https://www.otcmarkets.com", headers=headers)
resp.text
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help , 
Now I'm facing a different problem , the HTML I get by this and the HTML I see in 'inspect'(F12) when on the website are completely different and I'm missing out most of the info I need , is there something that might cause that data loss? mybe another header might help?

Comment: Requests and urllib are not able to run JavaScript-Code that may be loading additional information.
You can either try to identify the necessary resources/links using the network tab in the inspect window.
Or you can take a look at selenium. This however opens your browser. Personally I am not the biggest fan, but a lot of people like it: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try those methods;

**Method 01:**

```
import urllib.request
html_page= urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.otcmarkets.com")
```

**Method 02**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html_page= urlopen("https://www.otcmarkets.com")
```

**Method 03 (Using requests):**

```
import requests
html_page= requests.get("https://www.otcmarkets.com")
```